# HDD missing space until reboot

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ntfs

I have a non-system HDD in my computer. There is no hibernation, pagefile, backup, volume shadow set up on that HDD. Recycle bin is empty. The OS is Windows 8.1 the disk is NTFS.

I downloaded some ISOs with a torrent client (qBittorrent), but at the end of download it used more space than it should, the actual sizes of those 2 ISOs about 120GB but approx. 210GB was used as Windows Explorer and Total Commander showed I downloaded many apps to find what is using that 90GB. but with no luck.

After I restarted the computer I regained that missing 90GB. I post 2 pictures, before and after restart made with MiniTool Partition Wizard.

Before restart:

[image: before restart]

After restart:

[image: after restart]

Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion, 1022.56GB means all directories and files should be that amount on that disk. It's the same if you add every directories under the lines of "E:\" as this is a tree view. Which is almost equivalent with the disk info header "Space Used : 1023.20GB" showed on the after restart picture.

Comment: OMG, It's not that hard to understand, others don't have difficulties with interpreting the pictures somehow. If you check the "Percent of Parent" column everything should make sense (100% ~ 57.57%+32.78%+9.19%). Same for the "Size" column, but if you go for the reward for leaving comments, Be my guest :)

Comment: Did you close all software that could have files open on E: before checking? Especially the Torrent program.

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of temporary space allocation was at work.

Probably Volume Shadow Copy, since those aren't always tallied as file space occupancy (as temporary file would be). But if you ran the tool with visibility on System Information folder, then it's not this.

Lost clusters created by BitTorrent ought to have been signalled at the next reboot, so I don't think it was that either.

On Unix you can start writing to a file, *delete the file*, and keep on writing. The space is obviously allotted to no file, but it is marked as used. Close the file or reboot the computer, the space is free again. Since NTFS supports the same FS concepts, it *might* be that BitTorrent uses this strategy to keep (some) temporary files in addition to partially downloaded torrents.

[This guy](https://www.reddit.com/r/qBittorrent/comments/xgdd5z/disk_space_not_clearing_up_after_deleting_torrent/) had a different version of your problem, curiously with 120GB files too, but reboot didn't help. Still, the space was *somewhere* he wasn't able to find using file searching tools, so it might be germane.